# Delete specific amount of rows from SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, sql-delete

I am trying to create a mass delete button. I am trying to have an input field, where the admin can specify the amount of rows he/she wants to delete.

So far, I am using the following code to try and delete the amount specified in the input field, but nothing happens and there are no errors in the error log:

**helper.php**

```
function deleteall($all) {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->delete()
    ->from('#__shoutbox');
    $db->setQuery($query, 0, $all);
    $db->query();
}
```

**mod_shoutbox.php**

```
if(isset($post['deleteall'])) {
    $all = $post['all'];
    modShoutboxHelper::deleteall($all);
}
```

**default.php**

```
<form method="post" name="deleteall">
    <input name="all" type="text" value="" />
    <input name="deleteall" type="submit" value="mass delete" />
</form>
```

I believe the SQL query is fine and that the problem is to do with the HTML in the **default.php** but not 100% sure. Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

**Update:**

`$post` has already been defined as I am using Joomla coding standards.

Comment: I don't know Joomla but shouldn't $post be $_POST ?

Comment: What is the type and value of `$all` inside `function deleteall` when you call it, what do you expect should `$db->setQuery($query, 0, $all);` do? - The SQL keyword your looking for might be the `LIMIT` clause btw. - it belongs into the SQL, not for the number of returned rows.

Comment: No idea what you are doing in that PHP code but you can use `LIMIT` in SQL to limit the records to be deleted: `delete from table limit 100`

Comment: @TrimbitasSorin - It's Joomla standards and has already been defined. sorry, should have mentioned that before.

Comment: Ok ... try to put `die($all.'');` before `$db->query();`

Comment: @TrimbitasSorin - this results in a blank page

Comment: Then try to put `$all=2;` before `$db->setQuery($query, 0, $all);` What happened? 2 records were deleted?

Comment: @TrimbitasSorin - tried doing this and nothing happens

Comment: Ok. I posted the answer below. Somehow the post parameter is not passed to that method. Without seeing all the code .. can't find the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do is not accomplishable due to below reason. How can you tell the db which rows to be deleted ? You obviously should have a filter. EG : `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 2999`. Here rows only which have a ID between 1 & 2999 are deleted.

Else what you want is `LIMIT`. EG : `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 2999 LIMIT 1000`. `LIMIT` can limit the rows to be deleted.

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Here you don't have any syntax errors, where you have gone wrong is the logic. Hope that explains everything. Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your post handler is incorrect. It should be $_POST['deleteall']

Comment: I am using Joomla coding standards and have already defined that ;)

Comment: Is mod_shoutbox.php included in default.php because I don't see it nor is the form action pointing to it.

Comment: yes, everything is included. The shoutbox is fully functional and all the other functions work, even the function to delete a single shout, but I just can't seem to set a limit. I can only delete every single row.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method `deleteall` is not receiving it's `$all` parameter (it received nothing so 0 is used instead by the query class).